# Send javascript variables to Mysql database

Tags: javascript, mysql, variables, insert

I am trying to create a basic form where the user can enter his name, a comment and click on a submit button. When user clicks on submit, his name, comment as well as geolocation (longitude + latitude) are stored in a database. I have only one problem: How can I store the javascript variable of his geolocation into the database?

I have two php files. Iamhere.php (gets the data) and Iamhere_post.php (insert data into database).

Answer (score 1):

Populate hidden fields in your form that hold the values you need.

Create fields **longitude + latitude** then populate them with the geo values using javascript so they are submitted with the form

Answer (score 0):

Populate a hidden field in your HTML form for each the latitude and the longitude:

```
<input type='hidden' name='latitude' />
<input type='hidden' name='longitude' />
```

Store your geolocation to a variable and add that variable to the hidden field:

```
var latitude; //store the latitude to this variable.
var longitude; //store the longitude to this variable.

document.getElementsByName("latitude")[0].setAttribute("value",latitude)
document.getElementsByName("longitude")[0].setAttribute("value",longitude)
```

Call it with your PHP script on your database insert like normal:

```
$_POST['latitude'];
$_POST['longitude'];
```